# send return key for iOS Appium python

Tags: python, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

When I test an iOS app using python under Appium, how can I send the return key/enter key?

I tried `self.driver.press_keycode(66)`. However, It throws me an error which `selenium webdriver` issue

```
File "/Users/workspace/IOSBDD/lib/driver_helpers.py", line 99, in input_and_enter
      self.driver.press_keycode(66)
File "/Usersworkspace/IOSBDD/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 695, in press_keycode
      self.execute(Command.PRESS_KEYCODE, data)
File "/Users/workspace/IOSBDD/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
      self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Users/workspace/IOSBDD/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 29, in check_response
      raise wde
File "/Users/workspace/IOSBDD/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/appium/webdriver/errorhandler.py", line 24, in check_response
      super(MobileErrorHandler, self).check_response(response)
File "/Users/workspace/IOSBDD/venv3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Method has not yet been implemented
```

should I change 66 to another number? Or something else?

Comment: you must use the **AndroidDriver** driver or you must type cast your driver to AndroidDriver in other to be able to use **pressKey()**. Then you will be able to use   **self.driver.press_keycode(66)**

Comment: How can I use AndroidDriver in the iOS project?

Comment: How are you starting your app? Which driver are you using? Use **AndroidDriver** to start your app.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell what is unlikely to work (Python bindings and when iOS >=9.X ).

```
driver.send_keys("\n")
driver.send_keys("\uE007')
```

For testing purposes, you can do 2 things. Locate the element that closes or completes that view, and click() on it; or locate the enter key on the on-screen keyboard (which should appear at that point.) I went for the former option in the end myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
self.driver.hide_keyboard('Go')
```

or

```
self.driver.hide_keyboard('return')
```

as per your requirement.

For me both worked like a charm.

Comment: But the first parameter is `strategy` which is one of: 'press', 'pressKey', 'swipeDown', 'tapOut', 'tapOutside', 'default'. I am guessing that you are just triggering the default action, if it doesn't recognise the provided strategy. https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/keys/hide-keyboard/